# Why does CBC-MAC need prefix-free inputs to be a good PRF?

Tags: cbc-mac

In the [FFX spec](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/ffx/ffx-spec.pdf), there is a note about using CBC-MAC as the round function.

> Security notes. The round function F is constructed in such a way that the set of inputs on 
>   which the CBC-MAC is invoked is preﬁx-free. (A set of strings is preﬁx-free if for any distinct x, y 
>   in the set, x is not a preﬁx of y.) The CBC-MAC is known to be a good PRF when it is invoked 
>   on a set of preﬁx-free inputs, assuming AES is a good PRP [23].

Why is it important that the input be prefix-free? The citation is for [Erez Petrank and Charles Rackoff, ‘CBC MAC for Real-Time Data Sources’, Journal of Cryptology 13(3), 2000, pp. 315–338](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs001450010009) ([paywall-free](https://sci-hub.tw/https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs001450010009), [tech report](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.53.2421), [preprint](https://eprint.iacr.org/1997/010)).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC#Security_with_fixed_and_variable-length_messages $\;$

Comment: Is this really a practical attack on a Feistel network that just uses CBC-MAC as its round function?

Comment: How could "a Feistel network that just uses CBC-MAC as its round function" $\hspace{1.58 in}$ invoke CBC-MAC on inputs of different lengths? $\:$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because CBC-MAC with inputs that are not prefix free is weak against existential forgery, meaning it is not a "secure" MAC.  More precisely, CBC-MAC is easily distinguishable from a random function (i.e. not a PRF) when the input domain is not prefix-free.  This is because an adversary can request the CBC-MAC of messages $M_0$ and $M_1$, and then xor the MAC for $M_0$ with the first block of $M_1$, and thereby trivially construct another message, $M_2$ (such that $M_2 = M_0||\overline{M_1}$, where $\overline{M_1}$ is $M_1$ with the first block altered).  $M_2$ will have the same MAC as $M_1$, which is a collision that should be very hard to find for a PRF.  Note that $M_0$ is a prefix of $M_2$.

CBC-MAC can be made secure by either i) only using it for fixed-length messages (because no message of length $l$ can be a prefix of any other message of length $l$), or ii) always prepending $L_m$, the length of the message, to the message and using CBC-MAC on the string $L_m || M$.

Comment: In ii), one has to only use it for fixed-length $L_m$. $\:$ Option iii) would presumably be $\hspace{1.4 in}$ composing with a [prefix-free code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code). $\;\;\;$

Comment: Yeah but an adversary against a Feistel cipher with AES-CBC-MAC as its round function won't have a MACing oracle, it will only have oracle encrypt/decrypt for the whole cipher.

Comment: @pg1989 - The known proofs require vanilla CBC-MAC to be prefix free in order for it to be a provably secure PRF.  The FFX authors evidently wanted to use the PRF-ness of CBC-MAC in their mode of operation without having to prove a non-prefix-free variant of it would still be secure when embedded in a Feistel construction. There's no point re-inventing the wheel if you don't have to.